# Deleted user name looks like a link in mobile sites

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

> [image]

It can be seen in [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/23633) post. In the full site, if user was deleted, his name is shown black and doesn't look like a link.

May it be changed to black in mobile sites?